# Azure Function - only deploy updated proxies.json

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-function-app-proxy

I have a scenario, where new function apps are being create every week and need to (automatically) proxy them form main function app.

I could not find any way to "just" updated proxies.json without re-deploying entire function app.
Any CLI Command / Rest API reference to just update proxies file ?

Comment: You can upload the file directly using this url: `https://<yourfunctionappname>.scm.azurewebsites.net/dev/wwwroot/proxies.json`. If you want to uatomate that, you could just upload the file using FTP

Comment: HI, any update of this question? Have you check the continuous deployment?

Answer (score 0):

what you need to do is to use [continuous deployment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-continuous-deployment).

You need to first have some repos like github repo. continuous deployment also called incremental deployment. It is specifically designed for the situation that you mentioned.